# Access violation writing location 0x00000000 while assigning values to a matrix

Tags: c++

I am implementing SVD and I found a code online which I am trying to use. I am getting the following error (Exception). Exception thrown at 0x003A3D43 in Project2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

```
int main()
{
    float **convA;
    convA = new float*();
    float *singular;
    singular = new float();
    float **Vt;
    Vt = new float*();
    for (int p=0; p < row; p++)
    {
        for (int m=0; m < col; m++)
        {
            convA[p][m] = (m + p)*2.5; //program breaks here
        }
    }

    dsvd(convA, row, col, singular, Vt); 
}
```

Function definition of dsvd is:

```
int dsvd(float **a, int m, int n, float *w, float **v);
```

Comment: `convA` only points to 1 pointer, which is null. going `convA[p]` goes out of bounds already

Comment: While it won't really help in this case, you should really be using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)) instead.

Comment: OK, I'll have to ask -- where did you get a code sample like this showing how to allocate a 2-dimensional array?  It looks like you're just guessing.

Comment: As for your crash, think of `new float*()` as being an array of ***one*** pointer to `float`. And that single pointer is initialized to be a ***null*** pointer.

Comment: Lastly, perhaps you should take a few steps back, [get a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and start over from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float **convA;
convA = new float*();
float *singular;
singular = new float();
```

What do you think you're doing here? You only allocated **one pointer** for `convA`. The parentheses after that only denotes initialization (to zero, by default). To correctly use it, you must allocate another area for that pointer to point at. Also, in the upcoming `for` loop, you're assuming you have enough space for rows and columns for `convA`, which is obviously wrong.

A correct way to allocate space is:

```
convA = new float*[row];
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    convA[i] = new float[col];
```

And to free the space, remember to do in the reverse order:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    delete[] convA[i];
delete[] convA;
```

Since you're writing in C++, working with raw pointers is generally a bad practice (unless you're implementing an allocator). You should try Standard Template Libraries. `std::vector` is probably a good candidate for your code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> convA;
convA.resize(row);
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    convA[i].resize(col);
```

The rest of your code would remain unchanged because `std::vector` has a handy `operator[]()` overload function, except that you should remove the deallcoation as `std::vector` handles it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your convA is a single float *, you have to specify how many items you are going to store in the array. And unless you are doing this for a class or similar learning I would seriously suggest you use std::vector instead of direct allocation.